# Using Different Keys in the FoxDot live coding environment for Python

Tags: python, livecoding

So lately, I've been trying out FoxDot for live coding music, and it's great! There's only one problem...keys.

You can change the scale simply by doing something like:

`scale=Scale.minor`

but it seems everything starts on C. Like what if I wanted to do an E major scale? How would I change the key to that.

It has got a whole list of scales, which can be accessed by:

`print(Scale.names())`

but it's all in the key of C.

I feel like there's some huge disconnect between what I am thinking and what I should be thinking.

If anyone wants to help out, That would be greatly appreciated. The docs can be found at https://docs.foxdot.org/

I tried registering for the message boards at foxdot.org and it suspected I was a bot, for whatever reason. This is the only place I can get help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your key, just type :

```
Root.default.set(3) # identical as Root.default.set("D#")
```

Also, I contacted the website's admin and you can now register in FoxDot official forum. Please also join us at Toplap, we have an active Lurk channel!

Comment: Let's keep Stack Overflow answers link free to 3rd party promotions, unless it's totally required. 